# Where to add Aggregration in Azure based Microservices architecture

Tags: azure, architecture, microservices, aggregate

We're using the gateway feature of Azure's API Management for, among other things, routing requests to our microservices.

For some requests from the UI (angular based), we want the UI to only have to do a single request to retrieve all the data it needs. For example the request might be to get dashboard data, where the data that makes up the dashboard would be sourced from multiple microservices.

The options we're considering are:

1. add aggregation logic using the gateway
2. add an aggregation microservice, which the gateway will call
3. add an aggregation service, which calls the gateway

For options 1 and 2, our UI would directly call the API Management gateway. For option 3, the UI would call the aggregation service, which would then call the API Management gateway.

We're leaning towards option 1, however it looks like this could get a bit complicated, as we might need some c# for the aggregation logic (or else use send-request policies, similar to that shown [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/api-aggregation-using-azure-apim)).

For option 3, we would likely have chosen a nodejs/express based app service. We haven't found any references where aggregation is placed before the call to the gateway (the closest reference we have is some similarity with the Two-tier gateway example shown [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/choosing-the-right-api-gateway-pattern/), which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhdai.png), where our approach for option 3 might look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd6S9.png)).

Our microservices are currently all written in java.

Which option should we go with?